# Ridge down middle of model when sculpting using a mirror modifier

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, mirror, mirror-modifier, sculpt-mode

I am attempting to create a simple human face as a practice, but I keep getting an odd line down the centre of the object. I am only using a mirror modifier on the object and haven't done anything to the object other than model it in edit mode and sculpt mode. I have checked for any internal faces on the object that may be causing this, but I cannot see any, does anyone know a fix for this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use a Mirror modifier when you sculpt, instead apply and activate the symmetry option (on X), maybe it's your problem here

Comment: whereabouts is the symmetry option? is it in the sculpting toolbar?

Comment: sorry never mind, I just realised I was simply in sculpting mode but still in the layout windows XD. thanks a ton for your help!